# ¿Como ejecutar sentencias postgresql desde la línea de comandos en CentOs 6.10?

Tags: linux, postgresql

Tengo postgresql 8.4 (5432) y 9.6 (5434)
y quiero ejecutar sentencias sql en la versión 9.6 (5434)
Tengo CentOs 6.10
Podrían darme una ayuda con los comandos

Comment: Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] para que ganes tu primera medalla, adicional pasate por [ask] para que mejores tu pregunta y sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: `psql` si no me equivoco es el cliente de línea de comandos. Ver: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-psql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer referencia a la instancia de PostgreSQL de varias maneras, todo dependerá de como des de alta las variables de ambiente. La parte mas sencilla es con el puerto, utilizando el cliente psql (el cliente por default de PostgreSQL) donde tienes el siguiente patrón de conexión:

```
$ psql -p [puerto] [base_datos] [usuario]
```

Ejemplo:

```
$ psql -p 5432 postgres postgres

$ psql -p 5434 postgres postgres
```

Con las variables de ambiente puedes hacerlo por sesión o permanente (esto escribiendo la variable dentro .bashrc) por ejemplo:

```
$ export PGPORT=5434
$ psql postgres postgres
```

Incluso desde psql puedes lanzar sentencias desde la CLI de CentOS y responderte por ejemplo:

```
$ psql -p 5432 -c "SELECT datname FROM pg_database;" postgres postgres

$ psql -p 5434 -c "SELECT datname FROM pg_database;" postgres postgres
```

Saludos!